# how to assign date time to highchart with intervals and date start

Tags: javascript, highcharts

HI In highchart is there any way to give time on x-axis as below

1) pass start time
2) give an array of time points
3) give unit of time

for example

```
start time will set as
pointStart: Date.UTC(timeArr[3],timeArr[1],timeArr[2],timeArr[4],timeArr[5])
where timeArr[3] -> year
timeArr[3] -> year
timeArr[1] -> month
timeArr[2] -> day of month
timeArr[4] -> hour
timeArr[5] -> minute

now set time intervals array as below
[0,60,120,180,240]

now give unit of time as 1000(which tells time in array is in seconds)
```

And then highchart plot the x-axis by starting from start date and then pick interval from time array and add to start time and create time for next datapoint

I ask this question because our old application uses JClass chart and I am converting from that and that works on the logic I give

Comment: please select a valid answer if any of the answers worked for you.

Answer (score 5):

Set the initial date with pointStart:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 1, 12) // feb 12, 2015
    }
}
```

Set the interval in the xAxis:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            second: '%H:%M:%S',
            minute: '%H:%M',
            hour: '%H:%M',
            day: '%e. %b',
            week: '%e. %b',
            month: '%b \'%y',
            year: '%Y'
    },
    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // interval of 1 day (in your case = 60)
}
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/ppazos/jjn7noqg/

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, pointInterval is what you are looking for:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointInterval

If that doesn't do what you need, then it should just be a matter of parsing your object to get it do what you need...

Comment: Actually I also want to give an array of time in seconds for data series. and that array will be for all the data series.So that for each data series point seconds will fetch from that array and will add to start time

Comment: So you can use pairs [x,y] where x is timestamp and y value.

Comment: Yes that is manual option, but I was just watching for option from API, like only give the time arrray, startr date once and API will plot chart for all series.

Comment: If you have regular data for series, use [pointStart](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointStart) and [pointInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointInterval). If you have irregular data, you can send only once timestamps, but still you need to concat that series on client side, to make sure each series will have data in format: `[ [timestamp, value], [timestamp2, value2] ... ]`.