# Starting Time Series Highcharts Plot at specific date/time

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm getting started with the Highcharts JS library and I'm having some trouble with starting my chart at a specific date and time. The chart is a stream gage chart so my X values are a date/time (in EPOCH format) and the y values are a gage height.

I want my chart to cover 3 days starting at midnight, 2 days prior to today's date. I'm trying to use 'pointStart' to establish the beginning of my chart's x values but it's not quite working. I'm getting my three day timespan but the starting point isn't the desired midnight.

What am I doing wrong? Here's my full highcharts code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#gChart').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            margin: [20,40,50,60]
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Date',
                style: {
                    color: 'black',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },          
            type: 'datetime',
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            lineWidth: 1,
            lineColor: 'black',
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    var curVal = this.value;
                    var dt = new Date();
                    theDate = new Date(eval(eval(curVal + 28800) * 1000));

                    if (theDate.toString('h tt') == "0 AM") {
                        var t = theDate.toString('M/d/yyyy');
                    } else {
                        var t = theDate.toString('htt');
                    }
                    return t;

                },
                style: {
                    color: 'black'
                }
            },
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            gridLineColor: '#222',
            tickInterval: 86400,
            minRange: 259200,
            minorGridLineColor: 'red',
            startOnTick: true,
            plotlines: [{
                color: 'black',
                label: {
                    text: 'Last Update',
                    align: 'Right',
                    style: {
                        color: 'black',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                    }
                },
                value: theData[theData.length-1].x,
                width: 1                    
            }]
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Stage (Ft)',
                style: {
                    color: 'black',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            lineWidth: 1,
            lineColor: 'black',
            min: chartProps["lowGraph"],
            max: chartProps["highGraph"],
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            alternateGridColor: null,
            startOnTick: true,
            plotLines: [{ // Flood Stage 2
                value: chartProps["floodPhase2"],
                dashStyle: 'Dash',
                color: '#FFDC14', //Yellow
                width: '4',
                label: {
                    text: 'FLOOD STAGE 2',
                    align: 'center',
                    style: {
                        color: '#FFDC14', //Yelow
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        fontSize: '10pt'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Flood Stage 3
                value: chartProps["floodPhase3"],
                dashStyle: 'Dash',                  
                color: '#FFA500',
                width: '4',
                label: {
                    text: 'FLOOD STAGE 3',
                    align: 'center',
                    style: {
                        color: '#FFA500',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        fontSize: '10pt'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Flood Stage 4
                value: chartProps["floodPhase4"],
                dashStyle: 'Dash',                  
                color: 'red',
                width: '4',
                label: {
                    text: 'FLOOD STAGE 4',
                    align: 'center',
                    style: {
                        color: 'red',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        fontSize: '10pt'
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' ft',
            formatter: function() {
                var curVal = this.x;
                var dt = new Date();
                theDate = new Date(eval(eval(curVal + 28800) * 1000));
                var d = theDate.toString('M/d/yyyy');
                if (theDate.toString('h') == "0") {
                    var t = "12:" + theDate.toString('mm tt');
                } else {
                    var t = theDate.toString('h:mm tt');
                }
                theString = d + ' @ ' + t + '<br><b>Gage Height: ' + this.y + ' Ft</b>';
                return theString;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                lineWidth: 2,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 2
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                pointInterval: 900, // 5 minutes
                pointStart: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate()-2,0,0,0,0)
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Gage Height',
            data: theData
        }]
        ,
        navigation: {
            menuItemStyle: {
                fontSize: '10px'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I always had trouble with that myself. You are probably looking for the setExtremes function, which is an external function (no idea why).

Comment: Check [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gbcLC/1/) the events: load: and tell us how this turns out. (line 36)

Comment: pointStart should be timestamp, not date object. Add .getTime() at the end. Also, try to set useUTC: false.

Comment: @Marco Poli - the min and max properties are used to set the extremes inline.  setExtremes() is used to dynamically alter them.

Comment: @Scole check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940512/how-to-assign-date-time-to-highchart-with-intervals-and-date-start/32357408#32357408

Comment: @Pablo Pazos - I appreciate the heads up. Unfortunately (or fortunately depending on your point of view), this issue is now moot. I was able to implement the Highcharts graph but our organization decided to go a different direction and so the app I developed was scrapped.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I had multiple things going on which prevented the chart from appearing the way I wanted. First, when you specify a dateTime type for an axis of your chart, Highcharts assumes that the date information is in millisecond Epoch format. The data I have was in *second* format so that was one thing I needed to correct.

The second issue was that my data's source ignores daylight savings (hence the hour shift). Once I accounted for these two issues, my chart's axis finally appeared as they should.