# Highchart time interval in x-Axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm working with Highcharts JS library,

Now I need to create monthly report. I have number of sales orders, which corresponding to days in month. For example at day 1, number of sales orders is 30, day 2 is 20....

But I only want to show in x-Axis (day) something like 1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30 and information about sales orders of each day is still displayed.

What option I have to use?

Thank you very much.

**EDIT 1**
Here is my js code

```
<script>
                                    var d = new Date();
                                    var m = d.getMonth();
                                    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);
                                    if (d.getMonth() === m)
                                        d.setDate(0);
                                    d.setHours(0, 0, 0);
                                    new Highcharts.Chart({
                                        chart: {
                                            renderTo: 'container_sales_report',
                                            type: 'line',
                                            height: 380,
                                            width: 415,
                                            zoomType: 'xy'
                                        },
                                        colors: ['#FF0000'],
                                        title: {
                                            text: 'Last 30 Days Reports',
                                            x: -20 //center
                                        },
                                        xAxis: [{
                                                type: 'datetime',
                                                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                                                    day: '%e of %b'
                                                },
                                                crosshair: true
                                            }],
                                        yAxis: [{
                                                labels: {
                                                    format: '{value}',
                                                    style: {
                                                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                title: {
                                                    text: '',
                                                    style: {
                                                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }],
                                        tooltip: {
                                            formatter: function () {
                                                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d/%m', this.x) + ' : ' + this.y;
                                            }
                                        },
                                        legend: {
                                            layout: 'horizontal',
                                            align: 'bottom',
                                            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                                            borderWidth: 0,
                                            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
                                        },
                                        plotOptions: {
                                            spline: {
                                                marker: {
                                                    enabled: false
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        series: [{
                                                name: 'Cost',
                                                type: 'spline',
                                                data: [<?php echo $purchasesData; ?>],
                                                pointStart: Date.UTC(d.getYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()),
                                                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
                                            }]
                                    });
                                </script>
```

Now the time interval in x-Axis is 7 days. It's fine but I wonder is there anyway I can control this interval?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940512/how-to-assign-date-time-to-highchart-with-intervals-and-date-start/32357408#32357408

Answer (score 0):

You can try tickInterval option for the x-axis.  E.g.

```
xAxis: {
     tickInterval: 5
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. xAxis I use datetime type. When I use tickInverval: 5, I got blank page

Comment: Can you pls try tickInterval: 432000?

Comment: Any errors in the JS console? Anyway, should be `86400000` - so it's one day, the same as here: `pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day`.